# "Open proxy" error message

Tags: ip-address

I just tried to create an account at Wiki, however I'm getting the following message:

> Your IP address is listed as an open proxy in the DNSBL used by LiteratePrograms.

What does the above message imply?  Have I done anything wrong?

What can I do to correct or avoid this message?

Comment: Sounds like your using a proxy or VPN.  Sites such as Wikipedia often get heavily spammed or vandalized from people that mask IP's

Comment: @Tyson I'm not using a VPN, this was my first thought too.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thank you for the remarks, just edited the question.

Comment: Go look your external ip up at http://www.dnsbl.info/

Comment: @Tyson I've just typed `ipconfig`, copied the `IPv4 Address` into the in box on the link you've posted and I'm only on a single blacklist, whose web site cannot be opened so that I can see the _for removal criteria_. Is there anything else that I can do?

Comment: Is that you external internet ip? Or a private ip? I.e. Behind a local router?  See if you get the same ip via https://www.whatismyip.com/